# hangparas and href: hyperlinks running onto new lines, but not indenting

Tags: hyperref, indentation, paragraphs

How can I get the text in the hyperlinked text in the second paragraph to follow the same hanging paragraph indent as the first? I've tried putting a new `hangparas` environment inside the `href` block, but that just generates a `\pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode` error.

I've posted what I hope is a complete example below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{0.25in}{1}
This is a demonstration that, normally, the hanging text mode will work perfectly, no matter what kind of silly text I put in it.

\href{http://google.com}{This is a demonstration that, normally, the hanging text mode will not work perfectly when I put some kind of URL inside it, and I don't know why.}
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the link text is typeset inside a group. This causes the paragraph to start *inside* that group, but end *outside* of it. The `hangparas` environment works by redefining `\everypar` to make it set the paragraph shape parameters. This happens inside the group, but TeX's paragraph construction uses the settings that are in effect when the paragraph ends. Since it ends outside the group, the settings inside the group are lost. You can work around this by starting the paragraph before the `\href` command:
`\leavevmode\href{some://url.address}{This is a demonstration...}`
Any text or command that starts a paragraph would work. If it were possible, ending the paragraph inside the group would also work, but the `\href` command won't let you do that.

Comment: Good catch! Maybe Heiko should look at this and add a `\leavevmode` at the start of `\href`; after all, `\href` is supposed to typeset some text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to look at the moment (it's a holiday here and I'm supposed to be social), but a quick work around would be to use your own command; e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myhang}{\hangindent=0.25in\hangafter=1\noindent}
\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{0.25in}{1}
This is a demonstration that, normally, the hanging text mode will work perfectly, no matter what kind of silly text I put in it.

\href{http://google.com}{This is a demonstration that, normally, the hanging text mode will not work perfectly when I put some kind of URL inside it, and I
don't know why.}
\end{hangparas}

\bigskip % But this works:
\myhang This is a demonstration that, normally, the hanging text mode
will work perfectly, no matter what kind of silly text I put in it.

\myhang \href{http://google.com}{This is a demonstration that,
  normally, the hanging text mode will work perfectly, no matter what
  kind of silly text I put in it.}

\end{document}
```